# generate multiple charts via loop for chart js

Tags: javascript, for-loop, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am trying to only have table tag, but have js generate the entire table. So I use createElement for headers, but within tbody.innerHTML, I am string concatenating string interpolated html that contains tr including canvas inside of a td.

I am dynamically generating this and within the for loop, I try rendering a row, then have another function to create generic chart but fit to specific id of canvas. Ex: bar_1, bar_2, ... I am also using getElementById for new Chart(ctx)

So basically for each row, I want a chart in a td. The issue is, it only shows me 1 chart and it is for the last row only when it should show up for all rows. Which makes me suspect selection by getElementId, but I tried querySelectorAll() id specification, querySelector(#) as well but no luck.

----bar.js---- snippet

```
let body = ``;
for(var item of productList){

body+=`<tr>
<td>${item.id}</td>
<td>${item.name}</td>
<td>${item.date}</td>
<td><table>`;
for(var props of item.items){
    let currency = props.units==="USD"? "$":""; 
    body+=`<tr>
    <td>${props.item_number}) ${currency}${props.price}</td>
    </tr>`;
}
body+=`</table></td>
<td>
    <div style="border: 2px solid blue;">
    <canvas id="bar_${item.id}"></canvas>
    </div>
</td></tr>`;
tbody.innerHTML += body;

renderChart("bar_"+item.id, item.items, item.name);
body=``;
}
...
function renderChart(id,...){
let config = ... //generic chart config
new Chart(document.getElementById(id),config)
}
```

Comment: can you add a working snippet

Comment: This is not a generic issue, how to generate multiple charts in chart.js using foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is, it only shows me 1 chart and it is for the last row only when it should show up for all rows.

`body='';` line 23

This line removes all charts created and searched by the `renderChart` function.
You might want to either remove this line, otherwise the DOMElement you are trying to access will be removed by the time it's accessed, or use `const element = document.createElement('DIV')` and append your element to the body and then pass the reference to that object to `renderChart(element)` to avoid ID generation

Answer (score 0):

I figured out issue was with async events I didn't know about were happening. Only time chart js won't let you create multiple charts is on the same canvas or if it is previously occupied until you destroy it.

```
let id = "bar_"+item.id;
setTimeout(()=>{renderChart(id, item.items, item.name);},100)
```

I did something like this within the above snippet. Issue was the extracting of string concat of id was slower than getElementById, which made getElementById get same one. However I was still getting diff canvas elements on console.log testing, so I don't 100% understand how solving one issue solved issue of the actual new Chart being created for each unique canvas.